# Integration of Weyl operators multiplied by quasifree state over a symplectic space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, oa.operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I am reading the book "An invitation to the Algebra of Canonical Commutation Relations" by Denes Petz. It is freely available for download [here](http://www.renyi.hu/~petz/pdf/ccr.pdf). In Chapter 9, he defines the Lebesgue measure on a finite dimensional symplectic space. To set up the notations, let $(H,\sigma)$ be $2n$-dimensional symplectic space and $\,dg$ stand for the Lebesgue measure induced on $H$ from the standard symplectic space $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Let $CCR(H,\sigma)$ denote the CCR Algebra over $(H,\sigma)$ generated by the elements $\{W(g):g\in H\}$ satisfying the Weyl commutation relations. I have a problem in understanding the following. He writes,

"Let $\phi$ be a Fock state on $CCR(H, \sigma)$. The integral

\begin{equation}
\pi^{-n}\int_H \phi(W(g))W(g) \,dg = P
\end{equation}
is norm convergent and defines an element $P$ of $CCR(H,\sigma)$."

My view: I understand that the integral under consideration is the Bochner integral and all I need is to find a sequence of simple functions converging in norm to $\phi(W(g))W(g)$. But I am unable to produce such a sequence.